# Not receiving all data with networkstream.read

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I'm using the following code to get newsgroups from a server:

```
sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("LIST active microsoft.public*" & ControlChars.CrLf)
networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
If networkStream.CanRead Then
    Do
        numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length)
        myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead))
        intLenMyReadBuf = myReadBuffer.Length
        intLenComplMsg = myCompleteMessage.Length
        swWriter.WriteLine("buf len = " & intLenMyReadBuf & ", msg len = " & intLenComplMsg)
        Loop While networkStream.DataAvailable
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry.  You cannot read from this NetworkStream.")
End If

sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("QUIT " & ControlChars.CrLf)
networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
tcpClient.Close()
networkStream.Close()
```

When I execute the code, the routine only receives one block of the data. However, if I go into
debug mode with a breakpoint at the loop instruction, I receive all of the blocks of data.
Am I missing something in the code, like a wait or something, that would allow the program to
receive all data like happens with the debug?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looping until `networkStream.DataAvailable` is not true. In a running application, your loop could execute so quickly that the sender doesn't have time to fill the buffer again.

You either need to loop until a specific condition is met. Examples:

1) All of the data that you expect has been received

2) A specific set of data (i.e. EOF) has been received

3) A specific time limit has been reached (i.e. if you have not received any data for 30 seconds, bail). If you are in an infinite loop, you should always implement something like this unless you intend for the process to go on forever.

I would change the processing to something like:

```
Dim fLoopDone As Boolean
' Initialize the timestamp for the last data that was read so that we wait up to 30 seconds
' at the start for data.
Dim dtLastData As DateTime = Date.Now
Do
    ' Only process the data if there is some available.
    If networkStream.DataAvailable Then
        numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length)
        myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead))
        intLenMyReadBuf = myReadBuffer.Length
        intLenComplMsg = myCompleteMessage.Length
        swWriter.WriteLine("buf len = " & intLenMyReadBuf & ", msg len = " & intLenComplMsg)

        ' Record the last time that we received data
        dtLastData = Date.Now

        ' Possibly add a check in here to see if you are done reading.
    Else
        ' If more than 30 seconds has elapsed since the last data arrived, break out of the loop
        If Date.Now.Subtract(dtLastData).TotalSeconds > 30 Then
           fLoopDone = True
        End If
    End If
Loop While Not fLoopDone
```

Comment: Thank you for your response competent_tech. I learned much from your comments and my program is working much better now.

Comment: @Kool: You are very welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow. Remember that if an answer to your question on this site helps you solve your problem, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the question to let future visitors know that this answer solved or helped you solve your question.